# Altium off sheet connector vs net vs ports

Tags: pcb, altium

I have difficulties to understand what are the differences between a net, a port and a off sheet connector.

I particularly don't understand when to use a port and when to use a off sheet connector when there are multiple sheet.

I see sometimes people use port and sometimes they use off sheet connector, while I still read that only net can be used in some situations.

Answer (score 10):

A net is a connection name. If you have a signal on one side of your schematic with a net name of "SIG_A" and you have another net name of "SIG_A" on the other side. Those two nets are connected. It's as if there is a wire that ties them together. Nets tend to be local to a schematic (unless you are using a power net - which MAY be global).

An offsheet connector allows connections to be made horizontally. What this means is if you have a large design that can't fit into one page cleanly, you can use off sheet connectors to "continue" your signals to another sheet (but on the same level). It's almost like an extension of the same sheet.

Ports allows connectors to be made vertically. What this means is that you can create sheet symbols that represent your sheet, and connect them together via ports.

I tend to use a multi hierarchical design because allows me to see how circuit sections or typologies are connected together and so I tend to favor ports. But on large designs, I use off-sheet connectors as well.

Answer (score 5):

**Net (Net Label)**

This names a given net. The Net name is only valid in the scope of a sheet. If you have multiple sheets where you give a net the name "SUPPLY", they will not be connected, because they are local.

From a programmers point of view you could see them as local variables inside a function (sheet).

**Port**

This adds a port to the schematic. If you use multiple schematic sheets, the sheet symbol of the sheet will get a new port. The port can be used to connect signals in a multi-channel system (see [this](http://www.altium.com/files/training/module%205%20-%20multi-sheet%20design.pdf) and [this](http://techdoc.altium.com/display/ADRR/Sch_Obj-Port%28%28Port%29%29_AD)).

A port is used to connect signals between sheets in a very controlled way. For a programmer it resembles strongly to function arguments and return values.

**Off-Sheet Connector**

Honestly, I have never used them. For me they look like "global" Nets. Something like GND and supply symbols. For better readability I would not use them if I don't have to. But that's something you have to decide on your own.

For a programmer they look like global variables (stuff that can be accessed from everywhere in the program). I guess they don't make it easier to reuse schematic modules.

**Summary**

I don't know your background, but if you have at least a little bit of experience in programming, you could see child sheets as functions in your program. And you can use the net labels off-sheet connectors and ports exactly as you would use variables.

Comment: RE "The Net name is only valid in the scope of a sheet.", this is only true if you have the Preferences set to make it true.

Comment: Regarding "Off-sheet connectors": I think I read somewhere that they are a relic to support backwards compatibility/import from old Protel (the pre 2005 name for Altium) projects. I can't think of a reason why you would use them in new designs.

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of style. Altium supports different styles depending on preference settings.

Look for a setting called Net Identifier Scope. The location might depend on which version of Altium you are using.

[image]

([source](https://techdocs.altium.com/print/212497))

In my experience, global identfiers works well for small designs (up to 4 or 5 sheets).  Hierarchical scope works well for multi-channel designs. For larger designs I tend to use "Flat" scope. But bondage-and-discipline fanatics might prefer hierarchical style.

I believe that off-sheet connectors are just a graphical variant of a port. They're not normally used in Altium designs, but they might be used if you import a design from another program.

Answer (score 1):

I've used upto 8 sheets in my projects and I never used an off-sheet connector.

Keep two things in my mind:

One, use a Net Label for local connections, that is connections within the sheet.
Two, use Port Connector for global connections, that is connecting different components/parts on different sheets.

This always works well for me, either working on flat or a hierarchical design.